# How to trigger only specific stage of pipeline with gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, jobs, stage

I have gitlab project with ci file:

```
stages:
 - build
 - run

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - (some stuff)
  tags:
    - my_runner_tag
  except:
    - triggers
  when: manual

run:
  stage: run
  script:
    - (some stuff)
  tags:
    - my_runner_tag
  except:
    - triggers
  when: manual
```

Jobs are created on every source code change, and they can be run only manually, using gitlab interface.
Now, i want to have possibility to trigger stage `run` with Gitlab API. Trying:

```
curl -X POST \
>      -F token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
>      -F ref=master \
>      https://gitlab.xxxxx.com/api/v4/projects/5/trigger/pipeline
```

Returns:

```
{"message":{"base":["No stages / jobs for this pipeline."]}}
```

Seems, like i have to define stage to trigger, but i can't find a way to pass it via api call.

Answer (score 2):

you are using the wrong endpoint, to do it, you need to follow the path below

1. list all of your pipelines and get the newest one
   `GET /projects/:id/pipelines`
2. list the jobs from this pipeline
   `GET /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/jobs`
3. After that you can trigger your job
   `POST /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/play`

Comment: Thanks, but what if my pipeline is not a newest one, for example there is a newer pipe, created from another branch, so i can't get pipeline with :id, i know only the ref name?

Comment: When you are working with api's, most of the time you will be using IDs. Another approach is to get your MR from the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) to get the ID of the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

you are telling your build to run at all times **except** for the time they are being triggered (api call is also considered as a trigger).

change your job definition to the following:

```
run:
  stage: run
  script:
    - (some stuff)
  tags:
    - my_runner_tag
  when: manual
```