# How do I make a specific stage of an gitlab pipeline public?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I have an application who when I click in button, the button trigger a pipeline in another project. After trigger, I get the informations like id etc.
I would like to turn a specific stage (build stage) of my Gitlab pipeline to public using Gitlab API, and redirect the user to logs of terminal that stage.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your **specific** question? Add your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and your runner configuration to your question (in short: [edit] in all the relevant details).

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to turn a specific stage (build stage) of my Gitlab pipeline to public using Gitlab API" has been outlined in *[How to trigger only specific stage of pipeline with gitlab API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63015014/367456)* as part of the [CI/CD Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd) on site, the relevant reference is **[Trigger pipelines by using the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/)** and the **[Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html)**.

The **[Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html)** includes obtaining the logs <sup>1</sup> so that you can "redirect the user to logs of [...] that stage.".

---

1. Get a log file: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-log-file